# VS Code snippet regex for relative path

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm coding in Elixir/Phoenix Framework using VS Code and trying to transform the following relative path

```
lib/shop_web/live/product_live/index.ex
```

into

```
ShopWeb.Live.ProductLive.Index
```

using snippets.

The closest to that was the regex below

```
"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(lib\\/|test\\/)(\\w)|(.ex|.exs)$|\\/(\\w)|_(\\w)/${2:/upcase}${4:/upcase}${5:/upcase}/g}"
```

who gives me the following output

```
ShopWebLiveProductLiveIndex
```

I could not find a way to insert the missing dots.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"test7": {
  "prefix": "al",
  "body": [
    // my version
    "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^([^\\/\\\\]+[\\/\\\\])|(\\.ex|\\.exs)$|([^._\\/\\\\]+)|_|([\\/\\\\])/${3:/capitalize}${4:+.}/g}",

    // your version tweaked
    "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(lib[\\/\\\\]|test[\\/\\\\])(\\w)|(\\.ex|\\.exs)$|([\\/\\\\])(\\w)|_(\\w)/${2:/upcase}${4:+.}${5:/upcase}${6:/upcase}/g}",
  ],
  "description": "alert line"
}
```

[Note: I made these work for both path.separators `/` and `\`.  If you don't need that you could shorten the snippet by a lot.]

Your version was very close.  I changed it to `\\.ex` just to make the dots explicit.

I also added a 4th capturing group `([\\/\\\\])` just before the 5th as in  `([\\/\\\\])(\\w)`.

Now that 4th group can be used in a conditional `${4:+.}` to add the `.`'s where the path separators were.

My version is a little shorter - it matches but doesn't use whatever directory is first, be it `lib` or `test` or whatever.  If that doesn't work for you it is easy to modify that bit of the regexp.  I shortened it to 4 capture groups.

`([^._\\/\\\\]+)|_|([\\/\\\\])` the end of my version:

`([^._\\/\\\\]+)` : match characters other than `._\/`, or
`_` : match it but we aren't using it so no need for a capture group, or
`([\\/\\\\])` : match just the path separator in group 4 to use in the conditional.

`${4:+.}` : conditional, if there is a group 4 (a path separator) add a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mark, my snippet to create a module in Elixir or Phoenix Framework looks like this now:

```
"Module": {
    "prefix": "defmodule",
    "description": "Create a module by the Elixir naming convention",
    "body": [
        "defmodule ${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^([^\\/\\\\]+[\\/\\\\])|(\\.ex|\\.exs)$|([^._\\/\\\\]+)|_|([\\/\\\\])/${3:/capitalize}${4:+.}/g} do",
        "\t$1",
        "end"
    ],
}
```

As the [naming convention](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#module-name-nesting), the output for the file in my question `lib/shop_web/live/product_live/index.ex` will be:

```
defmodule ShopWeb.Live.ProductLive.Index do

end
```